# JCoIDocServer with own DestinationDataProvider not working

Tags: sapjco3

I want to use a own DestinationDataProvider for a JCoIDocServer.

I have registered my provider with:

```
Environment.registerDestinationDataProvider
```

When I call

```
JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("SAP_DEST_" + connector.name + "_server");
```

my data provider is called.

But when I use:

```
JCoIDocServer server = JCoIDoc.getServer("SAP_DEST_" + connector.name + "_server");
```

My provider is not called (I debugged it), and I get this exception:

```
com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException: (106) JCO_ERROR_RESOURCE: Server SAP_DEST_TestSap_server does not exist
at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.StandaloneServerFactory.update(StandaloneServerFactory.java:338)
at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.StandaloneServerFactory.getServerInstance(StandaloneServerFactory.java:175)
at com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.JCoIDoc.getServer(JCoIDoc.java:301)
at com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.JCoIDoc$getServer.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at com.lomnido.service.SapService.$tt__startServer(SapService.groovy:84)
at com.lomnido.service.SapService$_startServer_closure2.doCall(SapService.groovy)
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple mistake, in order to get your server you have to first register the server data provider as well..

com.sap.conn.jco.ext.Environment.registerServerDataProvider(serverDataProvider);